# share value between two select option and use same function for change value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter-3

i have create two select option for large and second for med and down screen,when user select this option according to that option data fetch using ajax, i want to user move large screen to small screen or vice versa option share change value between them and fetch data according to change value.
And can i use same function of change value for different id of select.

two div for select
for mobile

```
<div style="width:31%;background: white;margin-top:-54px;height:42px"class="hide-on-large-only"> 

  <select id="select_mob">
     <?php if(isset($location) && !empty($location)){
            foreach($location as $row){

            <option value="<?php echo $row->loc_id;?>"><?php echo $row->loc_name;?></option>
            <?php }
       }?>
   </select>
</div>
```

for large screen

```
<div style="width:31%;background: white;margin-top:-54px;height:42px"class="row hide-on-med-and-down"> 

  <select id="loc_select">
     <?php if(isset($location) && !empty($location)){
            foreach($location as $row){

            <option value="<?php echo $row->loc_id;?>"><?php echo $row->loc_name;?></option>
            <?php }
       }?>
   </select>
</div>
```

script code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var location_id = $('#loc_select').val();
   var queryString = {location_id:location_id};
   get_product_list(queryString);
});
$('#loc_select').on('change', function() {
  var location_id = $('#loc_select').val();
  alert(location_id);
  $("#myId").html('');
  var queryString = {location_id:location_id};
  get_product_list(queryString);
});

function get_product_list(queryString){
            var html      = ''; 
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo base_url();?>site/product_list',
                data:queryString,
                async: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    $('#list').html('<div id="product_list" class="carousel" ></div>');
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                        html = '<div class="carousel-item" style="height: 600px" >';
                        html+=            '<div class="card" >';
                        html+=               '<div class="card-image">';
                        html+=                  '<div class=" pulse green center-align right" style="width:70px;height:20px;margin-left:15px;margin-top:10px;color:white"><span style="margin-top:-10px"><b>'+data[i].discount+'% OFF</b></span></div>';
                        html+=                    '<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>'+data[i].product_image+'" class="responsive-img">';
                        html+=                    '<div class="card-content">';
                        html+=                        '<span>'+data[i].product_name+'</span>';
                        html+=                        '<h6><span>'+data[i].wait+data[i].unit+'</span></h6>';
                        html+=                        '<h6><span class="fa fa-inr">'+data[i].price+'</span></h6>';
                        html+=                        '<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small #ff6d00 orange accent-4 right-align"><i class="material-icons left">local_grocery_store</i>Cart</a>';
                        html+=                    '</div>';
                        html+=                '</div>';
                        html+=            '</div>';
                        html+=        '</div>';
                        $("#product_list").append(html);
                        var owl = $("#product_list");
                            $(owl).carousel({
                                dist:0,
                                shift:0,
                                padding:10,
                                numVisible:3, 
                            });   

                    }

                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('Could not get Data from Database');
                }    
            });

    }
```